# Handlebars template to create a list in Backbone

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

I am using Moustache as my templating for a Rails App that uses Backbone.js on the frontend. I am able to fetch the proper data but am struggling with getting it to populate my list. Here is the code...

articles_router.js

```
Rssreader.Routers.Articles = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'articles/:id': 'show'
  },

  initialize: function(){
    this.collection = new Rssreader.Collections.Articles();
    this.collection.fetch();
  },

  index: function(){
    var model = new Rssreader.Models.Article({collection: this.collection});
    model.fetch({
      success: function(model){
        var view = new Rssreader.Views.ArticlesIndex({model: model});
        $('#articles').html(view.render().el);
        // console.log(view.render().el);
      }
    });
  }

});
```

articles_index.js

```
Rssreader.Views.ArticlesIndex = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['articles/index'],

  initialize: function(){
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );
    console.log(this.model.toJSON({}));
    return this;
  }

});
```

This is the model in article.js

```
Rssreader.Models.Article = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/articles',

  defaults: {
    "name": "default name",
    "summary": "default summary",
    "url": "default url",
    "published_at": "default published date",
    "guid": "default guid"
  }
});
```

And here is the template.

```
<ul class="article_list">
  {{#articles}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/articles}}
</ul>
```

I have tried many iterations of this template and it does not seem to print anything. However I can console.log the data to be traversed just before I call the template so I know it has the data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handlebars `#each` helper (if you have `{articles: [{name: '1'}]}`) or create your own (if you have `[{name: '1'}]`):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('articles', function(context, options) {
  var ret = "";

  for(var i=0, j=this.length; i<j; i++) {
    ret = ret + options.fn(this[i]);
  }

  return ret;
});
```

The template itself is like your template :

```
<ul class="article_list">
  {{#articles}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/articles}}
</ul>
```

**Edit**

In your code you have used collection for articles, with Handlebars `#each` :

```
<ul class="article_list">
  {{#each collection}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating an ArticlesView with a collection, then attempting to render a model.

There's a few different ways to iterate over the collection and render its models, but the closest to what you have would be:

```
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template({articles: this.collection.toJSON()}) );
    console.log(this.collection.toJSON());
    return this;
  }
```

and a template like

```
<ul class="article_list">
  {{#each articles}}
  <li>{{name}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Handlebars as in the title. My mistake. Anyway I got it to work. Thanks for the input everybody!